# SQL GROUP BY question

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table:

`id group data

1  a     10

2  a     20

3  b     10

4  b     20`

I want to get ids of records with max "data" value grouped by "group", i.e.

`id

2

4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Portable solution:

```
SELECT T1.id
FROM yourtable T1
JOIN (
    SELECT grp, MAX(data) AS data
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY grp
) T2
WHERE T1.grp = T2.grp AND T1.data = T2.data
```

PostgreSQL solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (grp) id
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY grp, data DESC;
```

PS: I changed the column name from `group` to `grp` because `group` is a reserved word. If you *really* want to use `group` you'll have to quote it.

Comment: ok, is this the only option? I mean, there is any way to avoid nested selects?

Comment: @Redfield: What database are you using? The best way  depends on the database.

Comment: @Redfield: Then use `DISTINCT ON`.

Comment: @Redfield: You also need to specify what you want to happen if there are multiple rows with the same maximum value. The two solutions I have posted do different things in this case.

Comment: @Mark: the "portable" solution is MySQL only because of the non-standard backticks. If you want to make that portable use `"` instead of the backticks

Comment: @Mark, I this case I 'm going back to the top, aggregating by one field and selecting the other

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Quotes don't work in SQL Server.  I renamed group to grp. Solves the problem! ;-)

Comment: @Mark: hmm, quotes work for me in SQL Server, but it might be some configuration that makes it more standard compliant

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I think you must have set QUOTED_IDENTIFER. OK so what about Access then, does that support double quoted identifiers? I still think my solution of changing the column name to grp was the more elegant way to solve the problem of portability, and you're going to have a very hard time convincing me to change it back to `"group"` - I'm sure he only picked that name as an example anyway. ;-)

Comment: @Mark: I completely agree: choosing a name that does not require quoting is definitely the best solution!

Answer (score 5):

A more modern answer using CTEs:

```
;WITH Numbered as (
    SELECT ID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group ORDER BY data desc) rn FROM Table
)
SELECT ID from Numbered where rn=1
```

PostgreSQL has some pretty decent documentation online, look at [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/tutorial-window.html) and [WITH queries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/queries-with.html). In this case, we partition the rows in the table based on which group they belong to. Within each partition, we number the rows based on their data column (with row number 1 being assigned to the highest data value).

In the outer query, we just ask for the rows which were assigned row number 1 within their partition, which if you follow the logic, it must be the maximum data value within each group.

If you need to deal with ties (i.e. if multiple rows within a group both have the maximum data value for the group, and you want both to appear in your result set), you could switch from `ROW_NUMBER()` to `RANK()`

Comment: Actually the CTE is not really needed. A "regular" derived table would work just as well: `SELECT id FROM ( select id, row_number() ... ) numbered`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - they're reasonably equivalent. I tend to write CTEs when I'm working with the windowing functions, but that may be because they're both novel to me (from a SQL Server background, and still mostly having to write 2000 compatible code)

Comment: Thanks for this example, it exposes clearly the usage of these complex functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id
FROM Table t1 JOIN (Select Group, Max(Data) Data from Table 
                   group by group) t2
WHERE t1.Group = t2.Group
  AND t1.Data = t2.Data
```